# Apache sharing pictures for vhosts by symlink not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, symlink, vhosts

I have three subdomains on my site, running on Apache on a v-Server under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

One productive, one that will be productive in future and a testsystem.

```
/var/www/vhosts/prod.mysite.com 
/var/www/vhosts/test.mysite.com 
/var/www/vhosts/v8.mysite.com (mysite.com is just a placeholder, of course)
```

`www.mysite.com` delivers the prod folder.

There are a lot of static graphics that are needed in all these subdomains/vhosts.

So I have `prod.mysite.com/images` (`/var/www/vhosts/prod.mysite.com/images`) which is symlinked to the other directories too, e.g. `/var/www/vhosts/test.mysite.com/images`

in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

is set.
but I always get a 403 forbidden on the other domains for files inside the symlinked directory. 
All Folders belong to the same user.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Please accept it if it did using the tick at the top left of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a  block inside your vhosts that are using the symlinked directory, so they have permission to serve files from that directory. Like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/prod.mysite.com/images">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Or if your config is still on the old "order allow, deny ..." format use that instead. Let me know any problems.

Comment: Tahnk you very much. But it didnt work for me, I'm still trying to get it to work. My Server is controlled by Plesk and Apache ich chrotted, perhaps that has influence on this.

Comment: Perhaps, yes. Try putting the path as it is from the chroot and see if that works. Could you post your virtual hosts config?